# How to use between operator for 2 date input parameters in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

My task is to get the records between 2fromdate and todate(given as a input parameters).
  i am not able to use between operator for 2 input parameters...

My query as follows...

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`testrunner`@`%` PROCEDURE `usp_GetAllTranasactions`(pFromDate nvarchar(30),pToDate nvarchar(30),pstatus int)

BEGIN

select 

ST.UserID,U.Username,

ST.SubscriptionID,

ST.DateOfSubscription,

SM.SubType,

SM.Details,

ST.Amount,

ST.EndDate,


ST.Status

from tr_t_subscriptiontransactions ST

Join tr_m_users U on U.UserID=ST.UserID

join tr_m_subscription SM on SM.SubscriptionID=ST.SubscriptionID

where **ST.DateOfSubscription between (pFromDate and pToDate) and ST.EndDate 
between(pFromDate and pToDate) and ST.Status=pstatus;**

END if;

END
```

here i don't know how to use between parameters..plz help me..i want to retrive record between fromdate and todate..hope u understand..

Comment: do NOT use `between` for date ranges, it is not best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume you want all transactions for the month of June 2014

In your user interface the parameter values are:

- from_date = 2014-06-01
- to_date = 2014-06-30

But you will evaluate against a transaction date & time. How do you ensure that absolutely every transactions on June 30 - right up to midnight - is included in the results?

Here is how: use 2014-07-01 instead of 2014-06-30, and here is what the query would look like - which does NOT use between!

```
SELECT
      ST.UserID
    , U.Username
    , ST.SubscriptionID
    , ST.DateOfSubscription
    , SM.SubType
    , SM.Details
    , ST.Amount
    , ST.EndDate
    , ST.Status
FROM tr_t_subscriptiontransactions ST
      JOIN tr_m_users U
                  ON U.UserID = ST.UserID
      JOIN tr_m_subscription SM
                  ON SM.SubscriptionID = ST.SubscriptionID
WHERE (ST.DateOfSubscription >= pFromDate AND ST.DateOfSubscription < pToDate + 1)
      AND (ST.EndDate >= pFromDate AND ST.EndDate < pToDate + 1)
      AND ST.Status = pstatus
;
```

AVOID `between` for date ranges because it INCLUDES both the lower and upper boundary values.

> ... equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

What this can lead to is an "anti-pattern" which look like this:

- where dt_field between '2014-06-01 00:00:00' and '2014-06-30 23:59:59'

but there are time units smaller than one second, so that approach is imperfect. Don't attempt to overcome the deficiencies of `between` by adjusting the upper value this way. The simple and more accurate approach is to use >= and < adjusting the upper value by one whole time unit (usually the next day).

Comment: sigh, clearly none of what I wrote made any difference. To make a date range accurate the upper boundary should be pushed up one day and you do NOT use <= ... really wish I could explain this more clearly.